# Inconsistent Multiprocessing.Pool performance across WSL and WinPython

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using python in WSL (bash on ubuntu on windows) and I'm comparing with WinPython. All tests performed on the same machine. Code:

```
data = dictionary of big arrays of size (124750, 4)

def compute_histogram(data, lmin=0, lmax=1, num_bins=200):
    bins = np.linspace(lmin, lmax, num_bins)
    indices = np.digitize(data[:, :2], bins, right=True)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(bins, bins, indexing='ij')
    Q = np.zeros_like(X)
    C = np.zeros_like(X)
    d = data[:, 2]
    for idx in range(0, len(indices)):
        (i,j) = indices[idx]
        Q[i, j] += d[idx]
        C[i, j] += 1
    idx = np.nonzero(C)
    Q[idx] /= C[idx]
    return (X, Y, Q, C)
```

Computation:

```
start_time = timeit.default_timer() 
results = {}
for (k,v) in data.items():
    results[k] = compute_histogram(v, -0.05, 1.05, 1000,)
elapsed = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
total_time += elapsed
print('Sequential: {:0.3f}s'.format(elapsed))

pool = Pool(4)
results = {}
start_time = timeit.default_timer() 
for (k,v) in data.items():
    def log(result, key=k):
        results[key] = result
    pool.apply_async(compute_histogram, (v, -0.05, 1.05, 1000,), callback=log)
pool.close()
pool.join()
elapsed = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
total_time += elapsed
print('Parallel: {:0.3f}s'.format(elapsed))
```

WinPython 3.6.1:

```
Sequential: 6.810s
Parallel: 4.058s
```

WSL Python 2.7.12:

```
Sequential: 6.958s
Parallel: 6.490s
```

WSL Python 3.5.2:

```
Sequential: 6.823s
Parallel: 35.733s
```

The sequential time is the same across all versions, which indicates that numpy is working properly (linked to openblas etc). However parallel code is much much slower in Python 3 on WSL. Any ideas what could be causing this?

**EDIT**
I removed ubuntu from WSL and installed arch linux instead. The problem remains:

WSL Arch Linux Python 3.6.1:

```
Sequential: 6.326s
Parallel: 35.847s
```

So at least the problem is not distribution-specific, but rather specific to python 3 (when running in WSL)

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm considering switching from my python data work from my Ubuntu dual-boot to just WSL.

Comment: I was not able to fix this then so I stopped using python under WSL. but i think there's a good chance this was fixed with later updates for wsl and python.

Comment: Have you tried with WSL 2? I wonder if the VM model of WSL 2 will be better here.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be limited to WSL 1 when it interprets Linux commands to Windows and that's known to have performance issues. The performance of WSL 2 looks much better, probably because it contains a real Linux kernel. See [Microsoft's comparison of the two versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions).

```
# WSL 1 (Ubuntu 18.04), Python 3.6.9, numpy 1.19.4
Sequential: 7.877s
Parallel: 40.677s
```

```
# WSL 2 (Ubuntu 20.04), Python 3.8.5, numpy 1.20.3
Sequential: 6.943s
Parallel: 2.618s
```

The program I use for tests is the following. The size of the array is scaled up by a factor of 10.

```
import numpy as np
import timeit
from multiprocessing import Pool

data = np.random.rand(1247500, 4)
data = {'a': data, 'b': 1-data, 'c': data**2}

def compute_histogram(data, lmin=0, lmax=1, num_bins=200):
    bins = np.linspace(lmin, lmax, num_bins)
    indices = np.digitize(data[:, :2], bins, right=True)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(bins, bins, indexing='ij')
    Q = np.zeros_like(X)
    C = np.zeros_like(X)
    d = data[:, 2]
    for idx in range(0, len(indices)):
        (i,j) = indices[idx]
        Q[i, j] += d[idx]
        C[i, j] += 1
    idx = np.nonzero(C)
    Q[idx] /= C[idx]
    return (X, Y, Q, C)

start_time = timeit.default_timer() 
results = {}
for (k,v) in data.items():
    results[k] = compute_histogram(v, -0.05, 1.05, 1000,)
elapsed = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
print('Sequential: {:0.3f}s'.format(elapsed))

pool = Pool(4)
results = {}
start_time = timeit.default_timer() 
for (k,v) in data.items():
    def log(result, key=k):
        results[key] = result
    pool.apply_async(compute_histogram, (v, -0.05, 1.05, 1000,), callback=log)
pool.close()
pool.join()
elapsed = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
print('Parallel: {:0.3f}s'.format(elapsed))
```